# Query Returning False Positive

Tags: marklogic

I am using the following query for fetching the records, but it is fetching the false positive results.

```
<cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <cts:or-query>
      <cts:element-value-query>
        <cts:element>type</cts:element>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">article</cts:text>
      </cts:element-value-query>
    </cts:or-query>
    <cts:element-query>
      <cts:element>body</cts:element>
      <cts:word-query>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">ace???</cts:text>
        <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
        <cts:option>diacritic-insensitive</cts:option>
        <cts:option>punctuation-insensitive</cts:option>
        <cts:option>whitespace-insensitive</cts:option>
        <cts:option>stemmed</cts:option>
        <cts:option>wildcarded</cts:option>
      </cts:word-query>
    </cts:element-query>
    <cts:or-query>
      <cts:element-range-query operator="&gt;=">
        <cts:element>expires-on</cts:element>
        <cts:value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2014-12-04T06:05:29.78Z</cts:value>
      </cts:element-range-query>
      <cts:not-query>
    <cts:element-value-query>
      <cts:element>expires-on</cts:element>
      <cts:text xml:lang="en">*</cts:text>
      <cts:option>wildcarded</cts:option>
    </cts:element-value-query>
      </cts:not-query>
    </cts:or-query>
  </cts:and-query>
</results>
```

The above query is a wildcarded query and should search for the 6 letter words starting from the "ace". But we are also getting the results which contain more than 6 letter words starting from "ace".

Following are the indexes we are using

1. word searches
2. word positions
3. fast phrase searches
4. fast case sensitive searches
5. fast diacritic sensitive searches
6. fast element word searches
7. element word positions
8. fast element phrase searches
9. three character searches
10. fast element character searches
11. trailing wildcard searches
12. fast element trailing wildcard searches

Also we are using the 'unfiltered" option while performing the search.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what your wildcard index setting are. That's important: if the index doesn't include the right information, the results won't match your expectations.

Take a look at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard to understand how the various wildcard indexes work and which ones you might want to enable. In this case I'd suggest `trailing-wildcard`, perhaps along with `element-trailing-wildcard`.

That query might also be improved with some optimization strategies. I'd avoid that `element-value-query` with `*` if possible. Instead use `cts:element-query($qname, cts:and-query(()))`. That that does the same job and it's much more efficient.

If `body` is a simple element it would be more efficient to use an `element-word-query` for instead of combining an `element-query` with a `word-query`. If `body` is complex — that is, if the text to be matched is in descendant elements — then you have a choice between using the element-query with the trailing wildcard positions index enabled, or setting up [element word query through](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/text_index#id_93943) for all the descendant elements.

Comment: It's probably because of the way you're embedding word-query in element-query. You could add the trailing wildcard positions index and that might fix it, but it would be better if you could optimize the query instead.

Comment: As per your suggestion, we changed the query to the following query

cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("body"), 
("ace??"), ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","whitespace-insensitive","stemmed","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1)

The query is not fetching any results, although i have many words which match the query.

Comment: That probably means your words are in descendants of the body element: element-word-query only matches text children of the named element. You could address that with element-word-query-through configuration: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/text_index#id_93943 — but in a case like this there may be good arguments for adding the trailing wildcard positions index instead.